# How to choose each element from an array in their respective order? (jquery, JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

I understand that my for loop assigns all array elements to the variable pickSound and that is why I am left with it only playing the last element. So how can I get it to play each element in order and start over once done.

```
 function show() {
        var sounds = new Array(
            "audio/basement.mp3",
            "audio/roll.mp3",
            "audio/gatorade.mp3",
            "audio/half.mp3",
            "audio/hotdogs.mp3",
            "audio/keys.mp3",
            "audio/heil.mp3",
            "audio/money.mp3",
            "audio/ours.mp3",
            "audio/pass.mp3"
        );

        for (var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++){
    var pickSound = sounds[i];     
        }

        $('#divOne').html("<embed src=\""+ pickSound +"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: Had a solution, but realized, doing that in a simple for loop won't wait for each sound to be played and finished.  Check [How to detect an audio has finished playing in a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619917/how-to-detect-an-audio-has-finished-playing-in-a-web-page)

Comment: this is not something you can do with a for loop. you'd need to either know the durations of the sound clips and use `setTimeOut` to play them, or respond to some sort of event raised by the `embed` element.

Comment: Sorry I should have added that each click of the button plays a new sound. So a new sound can be played at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *" I should have added that each click of the button plays a new sound. So a new sound can be played at any time."*

I take it that means the sounds aren't to be played continuously on an automatic loop. You intend for a click of a button to play whichever sound is next and then stop?

In the following code the `nextSound` variable holds the index of whatever sound should be played next. When a button is clicked (insert your button's ID or other selector as appropriate) the file name associated with that index is used and then `nextSound` is incremented using the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) to loop back to zero when it gets to the end of the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var sounds = ["audio/basement.mp3",
                 "audio/roll.mp3",
                 "audio/gatorade.mp3",
                 "audio/half.mp3",
                 "audio/hotdogs.mp3",
                 "audio/keys.mp3",
                 "audio/heil.mp3",
                 "audio/money.mp3",
                 "audio/ours.mp3",
                 "audio/pass.mp3"],
       nextSound = 0;

    $("#yourButtonIDHere").click(function() {
       $('#divOne').html("<embed src=\""+ sounds[nextSound] +"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
       nextSound = (nextSound + 1) % sounds.length;
    });
});
```

Note also that it is generally recommend to declare arrays with the square bracket `[]` array literal syntax rather than `new Array()`.

Comment: Hey this works beautifully. Thank you for the help. The mod operator always confused me.

Comment: You're welcome. You can of course say `nextSound++; if (nextSound >= sounds.length) nextSound = 0;`, but the mod operator does the same thing when used as shown.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `audio` element and the `ended` event.

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" controls preload></audio>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    var audioEl = document.getElementById('audio'),
        counter = -1,
        songs = [
            'http://forestmist.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/html5-audio-loop.mp3',
            'http://www.quackit.com/music/good_enough.mp3',
            'http://forestmist.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/html5-audio-loop.mp3',
            'http://www.quackit.com/music/good_enough.mp3'];

    function nextSong() {
        audioEl.removeEventListener('ended', nextSong);

        if (songs[++counter]) {
            audioEl.src = songs[counter];
            audioEl.addEventListener('ended', nextSong);
            audioEl.play();
        } else {
            alert('All done!');
        }
    }

    nextSong();
}());​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mUdfw/1/)