# Run functions consecutively

Tags: javascript

I have two functions: one plays audio, another one async function that should run after. I should run this sequence N times.
But the problem is it runs in parallel. When the audio start playing second function also runs.
The question is: how to run this functions consequently? The second function should run when the audio is finished.

```
  const [song] = useState(typeof Audio !== 'undefined' && new Audio())

  function playSong(songNum) {
    song.src = songs[songNum]
    song.play()
  }

  async function finalFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
      playSong(i)
      await secondFunction().then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    }
  }
```

I tried to add promise, but it didn't help, it only runs the first function.

```
  function playSong(songNum) {
    return new Promise(() => {
      song.src = songs[songNum]
      song.play()
    })
  }

  async function finalFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
      await playSong(i).then(() =>
        secondFunction().then((res) => {
          console.log(res)
        }),
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: by "consequently" did you mean "consecutively"? or "as a consequence" as in because of some action?

Comment: FWIW seems like you are asking for "Promise" here ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40029867/125981

Comment: Where is `song` defined? What is it? You're setting a src, calling play()... More information regarding this `song` object is required. It probably provides a way to listen to the end of the song - and you'll need to use that in order to set things up as you want.

Comment: 1. Your Promise is never resolved (or rejected). 2. Why are you mixing await and .then()? 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619917/how-to-detect-an-audio-has-finished-playing-in-a-web-page

Comment: `song.src ` and `song.play` both refer to an unwritten song here.

Comment: If you want one function to run after another, then you want the functions to run **synchronously**, which is how JavaScript natively runs all functions. The JS runtime is only synchronous, so there's nothing special you have to do for that to happen.

Comment: It sounds like this is less a question about "making functions run consecutively" (which JavaScript does by default, I don't know of a language which doesn't) but rather "detecting when [an `Audio` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) has stopped playing".  Re-framing the question to address the underlying issue will help your Google searches.

Comment: @DallogFheir it's a good question, if I won't add `await` I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
async function finalFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    
      const songSrc = songs[i];
      const audio = new Audio(songSrc);
      
      audio.play();
      
      await new Promise( resolve => {
            audio.addEventListener("ended", resolve)
      })

      
      await secondFunction()
    }
    
    // all done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your finalFunction a promise because it's asynchronous.

You can extract all your logic all into one function then make your finalFunction a promise, and then run your code how many times you need to.

Comment: What does this mean? Async functions return Promises by default.

Comment: So you create a function which runs both playSong and finalFunction. However instead of just doing this normally you wrap each in a Promise and then outside of the function you run it as many times as you need to

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but a starting point to get you on the right track. You will need to adjust it a bit to make it work for your specific use case and incorporate additional functions if you want to.

The idea is to to create a playback chain using a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event to wait for the sound to play.

The `playInSequence` function then recursively calls itself, until there are no songs left. You can also wait for another promise before continuing with the playback.

```
function playSong(songNum){

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        let song = new Audio();

        song.addEventListener('ended', () => {

            resolve();

        });

        song.src = songs[songNum];
        song.play();

    });

}

function playInSequence(currentIndex){

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        playSong(currentIndex).then(() => {

            if(currentIndex + 1 < songs.length){

                playInSequence(currentIndex + 1).then(() => {

                    resolve();

                });

            }
            else{

                resolve();

            }

        });

    });

}

playInSequence(0).then(() => {

    console.log('All done.');

});
```